# Are there any good testing plaftorms for testing commandline Java batch software?

Tags: java, testing

I've got a Java software that reads settings from properties files and database, reads input files from a directory and creates output files in another directory. It also makes modifications to database.

I need to improve testing of this software from being manual to automatic. Currently the user copies some files to input directory, executes the program and inspects the files in the output director. I'd like to automate this to just running the tests and inspecting the test result file. The test platform would have a expected result file(s) for each input file. The test results should be readable by people that are not programmers :)

I don't want to do this in a jUnit test in the build phase because the tests have to be executed against development and test environments. Is there any tools/platforms that could help me with this or should I build this kind of thing from scratch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend to use [TestNG](http://testng.org/doc/index.html) testing framework.

This is functionality testing framework, which provides similar to jUnit functionality, but has a number of features specific to functional testing - like test dependencies, groups etc.

> The test results should be readable by
>   people that are not programmers :)

You can implement your own test listener and use it to build custom test report.